# How to integrate Custom automation framework with MTM

Tags: c#, tfsbuild, build-automation, microsoft-test-manager

We have a custom automation framework in place. So for running scripts we have a windows application for trigger some test case. Test cases are simple C# methods and we invoke them using Reflection.

Now My requirement is to integrate this framework with MTM. and would like to have continuous integration in process. This means I want if some build comes then some of the test case will automatically start running to secure our code.

How can I achieve this?

More specifically my requirement is I pushed some code related to some PBI, So the testcase related to that requirement should automatically run.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the CI ([continuous integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/example-continuous-testing)) is against the build process in TFS.

If you mean run the tests using custom test framework, then you need to create a Test Adapter accordingly, so that VS and the Build server can pick up the tests. Here is a good article for your reference on how to do this: [Authoring a new Visual studio unit test adapter](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bhuvaneshwari/2012/03/13/authoring-a-new-visual-studio-unit-test-adapter/)

Actually you can run the tests in build process, with the CI set, the new build will be triggered once a new change checked in, then the tests will run automatically. Refer to below articles for details:

- vNext build - [Testing in Continuous Integration and Continuous
  Deployment Workflows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/05/29/testing-in-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-workflows/)
- Xaml build - [TFS, Automated Testing and Continuous Integration](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534798/TFS-Automated-Testing-and-Continuous-Integration)

---

If you still want to use MTM, you can reference below articles:

- [Automate a test case in Microsoft Test Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx)
- [Continuous Delivery with TFS: Running Automated Web Tests with
  MTM](https://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-running-automated-web-tests-mtm/)